# Simple code works on Pen, but not on my editor

Tags: jquery, html, css

This Code does not work using an editor and  a browser. But it does work on Pen, the coding test form. I am really confused.

The point is to simply change the menu from horizontally lined up, to vertically listed, when the width is reduced to under 980 px.

```css
/*media*/

@media screen and (max-width: 980px){
nav{background-color:white;width:100%;height:auto;}
 nav ul {font-family:jsr; font-size:18px; background-color:white;}
      .ul li{float:none;display:block;}
           nav li{float:none;display:block;}
               li a { float:none;color: black; text-align: center;padding: 14px 16px; text-decoration: none; }
                  /* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
               li a:hover {border-bottom:2px solid #113a21;      color:black; }

}


/*Navigation*/

  .ul li{float:left;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<nav>
  <span class="menu-trigger">Menu</span>
  <ul class="ul">
    <li id="first"><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Vl.html">Verleih</a></li>
    <li><a href="S.html">Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="Vr.html">Vereine</a></li>
    <li><a href="U.html">&Uumlber Uns</a></li>
    <li><a href="K.html">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What editor are you using and what happens? Does your editor provide any error messages? And why the jQuery tag? I see no jQuery nor JavaScript.

Comment: I am using text-wrangler. and no, it does not. However, the exact same code works in pen!

Comment: I expect a problem may be coming from `font-family:jsr`, which is not defined and should probably be `font-family: "jsr"`...

Comment: did you add viewport meta tag?

Comment: I tried it now with:<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">, but that didn't change it.

Comment: however, I tried changing the background color of an element earlier - and that did work in the reduced size. Just, the float:left/display:inline of the links doesn't go away.

Comment: make them !important

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I am gong to die in shame now. I didn't open the right file to open in my browser. So I just obsessed 45 min on a problem that was never there. Not even sure what to say now.

Comment: Ok, actually the problem was, that I had to position the media query UNDER the normal css in my document!